Totally $p$-adic elements in cyclotomic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$
Let $p$ be a prime number and fix $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$. An element $\alpha \in \bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ is called totally $p$-adic if $p$ splits completely in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ (or equivalently if its $\mathbb{Q}$-minimal polynomial splits over the field of $p$-adic numbers $\mathbb{Q}_p$). The set of totally $p$-adic numbers is denoted by $\mathbb{Q}^{t.p}$.
I would like to understand what the totally $p$-adic elements in a cyclotomic field look like. For a positive integer $N$, let $\zeta_N = e^\frac{2\pi i}{N}$ be a primitive root of unity of order $N$. Reading on the internet, I found that $\mathbb{Q}^{t.p} \cap \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_N) = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{\gcd(p-1,N)})$ but I cannot figure out a complete proof.
I think I proved the fact that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{\gcd(p-1,N)}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}^{t.p} \cap \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_N)$. Indeed, it follows from Hensel's Lemma that $\zeta_{p-1}\in\mathbb{Q}^{t.p}$. Then $$\zeta_{\gcd(p-1,N)}=\zeta_{p-1}^{\frac{p-1}{\gcd(p-1,N)}} = \zeta_{N}^{\frac{N}{\gcd(p-1,N)}} \in \mathbb{Q}^{t.p}\cap\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_N).$$
As for the other inclusion, I need to show that if $\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_N)$ is totally $p$-adic, then $\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{\gcd(p-1,N)})$. I managed to show that, if we assume that there exists a cyclotomic subfield $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_M)\subset\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_N)$ containing $\alpha$ such that $p$ splits completely in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_M)$, then $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_M)\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{\gcd(p-1,N)})$. I do not see if it is possible to derive the statement from this special case or if there is a direct proof I am missing.

i might be turned around -- given the sentence starting "iI managed to show that, if we assume there exists..."-- but then you could take $M = N$ and you are done, right?

In that case, I am assuming that $p$ splits completely in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_M)$, which is not necessarily true in the whole $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_N)$.

great, I get it!
